# Bitnami stack of odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, bitnami

I am not sure should I ask this question here or not.

Can anyone tell me where I can get "bitnami stack of Odoo 8" for linux. I need it badly. I am using Xubuntu 16.04.

At present, in bitnami site only odoo 10 and odoo 11 available. Old versions are not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it at the following link:

- https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacks/odoo/8.0-17/bitnami-odoo-8.0-17-linux-x64-installer.run
  `md5:5c8795183334d9bd969eef3ad834a599`

Comment: If you don't mind, may I ask you something? How did you get this link? Why bitnami old stacks are not available publicly?

Comment: Bitnami developer here! We don’t have a public repository with old versions because these versions can contains bugs, security issues, etc (fixed in the new ones) so we provide these versions on demand to avoid shared hypothetical problematic versions. You can request any old version visiting https://community.bitnami.com